# databricks doesn't see submodule

Tags: databricks

I have a problem with databricks.
I have a structure:

```
root:
file1.py
--------
    -subdirectory:
    module1.py
    module2.py
    .........
```

in the file file1.py I use modules from subdirectory:

```
import subdirectory.module1
```

But databricks doen't see this module and I get an error that this module doesn't exist.

Thanks!

Comment: Does anybody know the answer?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a %run command, which will import all the functions there.

%run subdirectory/module1.py

Vasyl

Answer (score 0):

you can create your functions in .whl(wheel) files, then you install in the cluster and in the notebook use the lib import, instantiate the class and use